# Centos - Sendmail smtp smarthost with authentication

Tags: email, sendmail, smtp

I would like to setup sendmail to send out mail using an external smtp-server with authentication. I've searched for solutions, but can't seem to find what I need. There are several examples about ssmtp and using gmail as smarthost, but then I read that ssmtp is not for servers.

For authentication I have:

- server: mail.server.remote, port 25
- user: username@server.remote
- password: password123456

Sendmail is installed and running. (Postfix is not installed.)

**How do I configure sendmail to use the external smpt server?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Edit your `sendmail.mc` and add:

```
define (`SMART_HOST', `your.smarthost')dnl
FEATURE (`authinfo')dnl
```

Create the file `/etc/mail/authinfo` with content:

```
AuthInfo:your.smarthost    "U:username" "P:password"
```

Make new sendmail config:

If you have sendmail-cf package installed:

```
make -C /etc/mail
```

Otherwise

```
cd /etc/mail
m4 ./sendmail.mc > ./sendmail.cf
makemap hash ./authinfo < ./authinfo
```

Restart or reload sendmail

Comment: When I run the make or m4 command, I get the following error: `m4:./sendmail.mc:27: cannot open ``/usr/share/sendmail-cf/feature/.m4': No such file or directory`. It turns out that the `FEATURE (``authinfo')dnl` line should not be directly after the define command, but should be put with the other FEATURE lines. The make succeeded afterwards, but a testmail via commandline doesn't arrive.

Comment: What is the maillog saying about your test email?

Comment: The log said: Temporary AUTH failure. So I've checked the login to be correct, and used the following AuthInfo format: `AuthInfo:your.smtp.server "U:user@your.smtp.server" "I:user" "P:passwd" "M:LOGIN PLAIN"`. This works! Thanks!

Comment: See also https://www.dnsexit.com/support/mailrelay/sendmail.html for basically the same info. Worked first time for me with sendmail 8.14.4.

Comment: @SPRBRN What is the `I:` for????

Comment: @SpencerWilliams - tbh I have no idea but it seems part of the format. So it looks like you add the username twice.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the space between the word `FEATURE` and thew opening bracket
Change it to ``` FEATURE(``authinfo')dnl ``` and it works fine